# Regex that grep numbers after specific string in multiple files and return average

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I would like to return the average of all numbers after a specific string in multiple files i.e.

We are given 10 files (file1.txt,...,file10.txt). Each file contains among others

```
Test1: Avg. length 24.01000, time: 0.579
Test2: Avg. length 22.02000, time: 0.879
```

with different numbers.

If we have 10 files it could look like

file1.txt

```
Test1: Avg. length 24.01000, time: 0.679
Test2: Avg. length 22.01000, time: 0.479
```

file2.txt

```
Test1: Avg. length 27.01000, time: 0.279
Test2: Avg. length 24.01000, time: 0.779
```

.....

file10.txt

The output I desire is the mean of the lengths and times of Test1 and Test2 over all files:

```
Mean Test1: Avg. length (file1_Test1_length+...+file10_Test1_lenght)/10, time (file1_Test1_time+...+file_10_Test1_time)/10
Mean Test2: Avg. length (file1_Test2_length+...+file10_Test2_lenght)/10, time (file1_Test2_time+...+file_10_Test2_time)/10
```

To grep the full output of Test1 I execute:

```
egrep -rh 'Test1: Avg. length.*' /home/timo/Documents
```

I'm not sure how to grep only the numbers. I tried

```
egrep -rhP '(?<=length )\d+' /home/timo/Documents
```

But I get an error

```
grep: conflicting matchers specified
```

I would be really thankful if someone could help me!

Comment: If you say "among others", does that mean there are _other lines_ besides the two you mention, but these two look exactly as reproduced by you, or that these two lines can in addition contain _other comma-separated fields_? If the latter, please explain what the structure of the line looks like exactly.

Comment: The files contains other lines. 
Abcsd
Test1...
Test2...

The lines containing Test... are always the same with exception of the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
$ grep '^Test.*Avg\. length.*time:' file*.txt | tr -d ',' | LC_ALL=C datamash -W -s -g 1 mean 4,6
Test1:  25.51   0.479
Test2:  23.01   0.629
```

This first extracts the lines that you show using `grep`.  I do this by matching the text `Test` at the start of a line, followed by the strings `Avg. length` and `time:` somewhere else on the line.  You may want to modify this expression (I don't know if it uniquely matches *only* the lines that we're interested in).

I then delete all commas from the data, because they mess up the interpretation of the numbers.  I do this with `tr`.

The `grep`+`tr` bit could also be done with `sed` as

```
sed '/^Test.*Avg\. length.*time:/!d; s/,//g' file*.txt
```

I then use GNU `datamash` to compute the mean lengths and times for each test.  I first tell `datamash` that whitespaces are to be used as delimiters using `-W`. The `-s` sorts the data, because it comes unsorted from `grep`+`tr` (or `sed`), to efficiently group the data globally.

Grouping is done with `-g 1` which defines the `TestN:` labels on each line as the grouping key.  Then, for each such group, the mean is calculated over the 4th and 6th whitespace-delimited column, with `mean 4,6`.

I set the locale to `C` (the POSIX locale) for `datamash`, because the utility may otherwise want decimal numbers to use comma rather than dot as a decimal dot.

Would you want to decorate the output a bit, do so with `awk`:

```bsh
sed '/^Test.*Avg\. length.*time:/!d; s/,//g' file*.txt |
LC_ALL=C datamash -W -s -g 1 mean 4,6 |
awk '{ printf "%s Avg. length: %s time: %s\n", $1,$2,$3 }'
```

This may output something like

```
Test1: Avg. length: 25.51 time: 0.479
Test2: Avg. length: 23.01 time: 0.629
```

Comment: I forgot to say that each file is located in a subfolder. Therefore I use
egrep -rh '^Test.*Avg\. length.*time:' /home/timo/Documents/ | tr -d ',' | datamash -W -s -g 1 mean 4,6
Then I get: datamash: invalid numeric value in line 1 field 4: '24.01000'
Another question: Can grouping be done by names e.g. -g 'timo' if the names would not be Test1 and Test2 but 'Timo' and 'Anna'? Thanks

Comment: @GeoRie I don't understand why you get a "invalid numeric value" error. That value does not look invalid to me. As for using `Timo` and `Anna` instead of `Test1` and `Test2`: You would have to modify your `grep` to look for `^[[:alnum:]]*:.*Avg\. length.*time:` instead.  `[[:alnum:]]*` would match any alphanumeric string.  _Always show data that is actually representative of your real data_.

Comment: the error also appears if I execute datamash -W -s -g 1 mean 6
datamash: invalid numeric value in line 1 field 6: '0.684'. I don't understand why '0.684' isn't a valid numeric value? Perhaps the value is from type string and must be converted into numeric?

Comment: @GeoRie This makes no sense to me. Do you have control characters in the data? I had to remove the commas from each line because these were interfering, but I can se nothing else in the data in the question that would be an issue.

Comment: Without using datamash i get
Test1: Avg. length 24.36000 time: 0.526
Test2: Avg. length 24.21000 time: 0.379
Test1: Avg. length 24.14000 time: 0.531
Test2: Avg. length 24.47000 time: 0.383
Test1: Avg. length 24.26000 time: 0.547
Test2: Avg. length 24.35000 time: 0.384
Test1: Avg. length 24.53000 time: 0.574
Test2: Avg. length 24.26000 time: 0.416
I saved this output in a file and try
datamash -W -s -g 1 mean 4,6 </home/timo/Documents/mytest.txt
Same result: datamash: invalid numeric value in line 1 field 4: '24.36000'
Could you try it, too, please

Comment: @GeoRie No issue copying the data from your comment and running the command (after adding newlines in the correct locations, obviously).  Check that file with `cat -v` to see if you can spot any non-printing characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119805/discussion-between-georie-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` solution should work:

```
awk -F'[ ,:]+' '$1~/^Test[12]/{l[$1]+=$4; t[$1]+=$6; n[$1]++;}
                END{if (n["Test1"]) {for (tst in l) printf("Mean %s: Avg. length %f, time: %f\n",tst,l[tst]/n[tst], t[tst]/n[tst]);} else {print "No input found"}}' file*.txt
```

This will parse the input files for lines starting `Test1` or `Test2` and sum fields 4 and 6 (the "length" and "time", respectively). In addition, it will increase the data counter `n`. In the end, it will either print the average (if any data was found) or an error message.

If you are sure that at least one file will be present, you can simplify this to

```
awk -F'[ ,:]+' '$1~/^Test[12]/{l[$1]+=$4; t[$1]+=$6; n[$1]++;}
                END{for (tst in l) printf("Mean %s: Avg. length %f, time: %f\n",tst,l[tst]/n[tst], t[tst]/n[tst]);}' file*.txt
```

Since all your files seem to be in individual sub-folders, the approach depends on your shell. In the easiest case, you can try

```
awk -F'[ ,:]+' ' ... ' subdir*/file*.txt
```